# Using the ContactPickerUI in a Windows 8 Store App

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, contacts, windows-store-apps

I want to add a new contact from my Windows 8 Store app and save it so it will appear in the People app which comes with the OS.

The documentation says there's a class `ContactPickerUI` which has the method `public AddContactResult AddContact(string id, Contact contact)` and that seems to do exactly the job I need it to do.

The problem is I don't know how to obtain a reference to a `ContactPickerUI` object, because the class cannot be instantiated.

If I try to do

```
var contactPickerUi = new ContactPickerUI();
```

I get an error message saying: **"The type 'Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.Provider.ContactPickerUI' has no constructors defined"**

There's a code sample online from Microsoft where they use the `ContactPickerUI` [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Contact-Picker-App-sample-fc6677a1).

The problem is that in that code they get a reference at that object when the application is activated from an external source (i.e. it's a share target) and that's not the case for my app.

Is there a way to access the `ContactPickerUI` when your application starts normally? Or is there another way to programatically add a new contact, without sharing it through the charms bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you misunderstood the purpose of `ContactPickerUI`. The API isn't used to add contacts so they would appear in People app (to do that, you'd have to use the API of one of the services People app is retrieving contacts from), but to add contacts to a list that will be displayed to the user when he selects your app as Contact Picker provider. That's the reason why you can only get an instance of the class when your app gets activated with `ActivationKind.ContactPicker`.

Comment: Sounds fair, thanks! But how do I "use the API of one of the services People app is retrieving contacts from"? Which services are you talking about?

Comment: @alex_and_ra I'm talking about the accounts you configure in People app. It doesn't have its own local storage, it depends on direcotry services like Google, Hotmail, Facebook...). You'd need to talk directly to one of those.